# Dependency injection use in "Clean Code" by Robert Martin

Tags: dependency-injection, clean-code, inversion-of-control

In Robert Martin's *Clean Code*, I encountered the following method on p. 195:

```
private void parseSchemaElement(String element) throws ArgsException {
    char elementId = element.charAt(0);
    String elementTail = element.substring(1);
    validateSchemaElementId(elementId);
    if (elementTail.length() == 0) marshalers.put(elementId, new BooleanArgumentMarshaler());
    else if (elementTail.equals("*")) marshalers.put(elementId, new StringArgumentMarshaler());
    else if (elementTail.equals("#")) marshalers.put(elementId, new IntegerArgumentMarshaler());
    else if (elementTail.equals("##")) marshalers.put(elementId, new DoubleArgumentMarshaler());
    else if (elementTail.equals("[*]")) marshalers.put(elementId, new StringArrayArgumentMarshaler());
    else throw new ArgsException(INVALID_ARGUMENT_FORMAT, elementId, elementTail);
}
```

Just a few pages earlier (p. 157), the book advocates use of dependency injection (DI) in order to structure our program better and facilitate testing in isolation.

Would the above example be the case where dependency injection should be used in order to test the given class in *isolation*, i.e. without also testing all the `*ArgumentMarshaller` classes?

We could have a factory object, which would create an appropriate `*ArgumentMarshaller` where needed - this would be consistent with the DI recommendations and also facilitate testing with mocks/doubles.

..or perhaps did I misunderstand something and the dependency injection applied here is not a good idea?

Comment: Can't you already test this class in isolation? Create an object, call `parseSchemaElement` and then check that the correct object was put in its `marshalers` array? It seems to me that the method you are asking about is a factory function...

Comment: As a private method, agrguably you dont need to unit test.  Wow, this function does far more than one thing.

Comment: @user949300: It does *one thing:* it parses a schema element.  SRP isn't about methods anyway.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Agree on SRP, but I didn't mention that.  Nor am I a fanatice Robert Martineer, but this is **his code**  This methods doesn't "do just one thing and do it well".  It validates something, it creates the proper XXXMarshaller, and it adds said Marshaller somewhere.  The create part should be separated, which would make that part testable since it is no longer a void method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply put, it depends.

Even though I am all for dependency injection in classes containing business logic, for this specific case and without knowing the context, even though the `Marshaler`s are instantiated directly, it seems the only work that is done with them is adding them do a dictionary based on some rule, but not actually performing any operations on them. And for that I would be OK with instantiating the classes directly in place.

If you, however, wanted to decouple the creation of `Marshaler`s in question, the factory approach is the correct one.

Dependency injection is generally recommended for classes which contain methods performing operations with side effects, such as writing to a database. In that case you want to know what the dependencies are so you are not surprised when a method `work` suddenly wipes your entire database even though, based on public API of the class, it shouldn't have access to it.

The only real improvement I'd have for this code would be to rename the method to `parseSchemaElementAndAddItToMarshalerCollection`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you could use dependency injection (DI) here, but let’s consider how it would be achieved.

The method you quote is essentially a factory class creating the correct type of marshaller based on a string input.

Therefore injecting a factory class isn't going to help us much. It separates the logic out into its own class, which could improve the code if it's a large class, but really it just moves the offending if block and hard links 'down a level'.

In order to abstract out the string x = type y logic, we would have to inject a dictionary of IMarshallerFactory each with an associated string key.

This is a neat approach and allows you to test the consuming class without testing the *marshaller classes as you state.

However you still need to instantiate the dictionary in your [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) setup somewhere, plus add a host of factory classes and interfaces.

Unless your code requires this level of genericism and the ability to have varying marshaller mappings at run time it could be considered overkill.